# Openshift Origin git push permission error

Tags: openshift-origin

I've installed "openshift origin" with the oo-install script. I can login into the web console and create apps, "git clone" works but when I "git push" I get a permissions error:

```
remote: Permission denied - /var/lib/openshift/5373c78ae138230657000005/app-deployments/2014-05-14_19-44-15.999/dependencies/python/virtenv/include/python2.7
To ssh://5373c78ae138230657000005@insultapp-test.apps.dom1.local/~/git/insultapp.git/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://5373c78ae138230657000005@insultapp-test.apps.dom1.local/~/git/insultapp.git/'
```

These are some of the folder permissions when I ssh into the gear:

```
drwxr-x---. 13 root                     5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root                     root                     4.0K May 14 19:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  4 5373c78ae138230657000005 5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 app-deployments
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root                     5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 app-root
drwxr-x---.  2 5373c78ae138230657000005 5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .auth
drwxr-x---.  3 root                     5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .env
drwxr-x---.  2 5373c78ae138230657000005 5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .gem
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root                     root                     4.0K May 14 19:44 git
-rw-r--r--.  1 root                     root                       57 May 14 19:44 .gitconfig
drwxr-x---.  2 5373c78ae138230657000005 5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .openshift_ssh
drwxr-xr-x. 11 5373c78ae138230657000005 5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 python
d---------.  3 root                     root                     4.0K May 14 19:44 .sandbox
drwxr-x---.  2 root                     5373c78ae138230657000005 4.0K May 14 19:44 .ssh
d---------.  3 root                     root                     4.0K May 14 19:44 .tmp
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root                     root                       64 May 14 19:44 .vimrc -> /var/lib/openshift/5373c78ae138230657000005/app-root/data/.vimrc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you ssh into your machine and run an ls -lah and show us the permissions on some of those directories etc?

Comment: @corey112358 I've just edited my post. I'll recreate the VM (which I deleted in frustration!!) and give a more precise folder permission details. And thanks for your reply.

Comment: Another thought is to make sure that if you ssh into your gear and run commands, that you are ssh'd in as the user that owns that gear, and not as root, as you could easily run a command and mess up the permissions within your gear.  Like if you had run npm install as root, it might cause something like that issue above.

Comment: I actually run the commands from a different pc and use the ssh info provided in the web console for the gear. These permissions are set anytime I create a gear either from the console or rhc. The same root permission on some folders happens when I create a nodejs gear.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same issue, but in a nodejs gear... "Permission denied on 'nodejs/node_modules/.bin/static". If I ssh into my machine, edit the code there and restart the app, it works, but then I can't use Git (and have to use vim to edit the files *yuck!*)